# Unable to fetch printer job history XML page using wget

Tags: linux, wget, xml

My aim is, to fetch below print history (XML) page,to my Debian box using wget,but not fetching contents of page. [image]

Commands Used:

```
wget -q  http://192.168.8.93/wcd/job_history.xml
```

Result I got:

```
root@vm-debian:~/ar_lab# cat job_history.xml
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN">
<HTML lang="en">
<HEAD>
<TITLE></TITLE>
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<meta content="text/javascript" http-equiv="Content-Script-Type">
<noscript>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=/wcd/js_error.xml">
</noscript>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#ffffff" LINK="#000000" ALINK="#ff0000" VLINK="#000000" onload="location.replace('/wcd/index.html?access=JOB_DON');" >
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your printer uses Javascript to redirect the page to the right location.

Wget does not understand Javascript.

The simple solution here would be for you to make the request directly to the redirected page:

```
$ wget -q http://192.168.8.93/wcd/index.html?access=JOB_DON
```

Comment: I tries this suggestion , but still no luck ( https://i.imgur.com/z3GcKx4.png )

Comment: Please don't use images of text. It makes it very difficult to read. Update your original post with any new information

Comment: Also, if you see the HTML source, it is making yet another javascript redirection. Unfortunately, you're going to have to manually follow all of these. None of the simple HTTP tools understand javascript. Selenium does, but it is too huge a project to throw at something this small.